# mt_rand in function causing parse error

Tags: php, function

I am working from some code I found online but modified the function a little bit.
My function is

```
function generate_random_password($length=10)
{      
    $letters = 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwxzaeiou';

    $result = '';
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
    {
        $result =. ($i%2) ? $letters[mt_rand(19, 23)] : $letters[mt_rand(0, 18)];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And I am echoing the random password like this

```
echo generate_random_password($_GET['length']);
```

The moment I added the mt_rand() in the $result line it stopped working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: When you give errors, **don't paraphrase**.  Don't say "It's a parse error."  Cut & paste the entire message so that we can see exactly what it says.

Comment: sorry about that now i know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parse error is because of `=.`.  It should be `.=` as follows:

```
$result .= ($i%2) ? $letters[mt_rand(19, 23)] : $letters[mt_rand(0, 18)];
```

Answer (score 1):

change `.=` instead of `=.`

```
$result .= ($i%2) ? $letters[mt_rand(19, 23)] : $letters[mt_rand(0, 18)];
```